# Find suitable density resource algorithm in Android

Tags: android, android-resources

If I have hdpi and xhdpi drawable resource in Android project, and if test device is mdpi, I saw that it use xhdpi.
And I found the reason is better result when scaling.
Is there any algorithm or table to find density resource in Android?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "algorithm or table to find density resource in Android", but [this article](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) might help answering your question. In particular: the section `Using configuration qualifiers`.

Comment: Thank you.I didn't mean tablet or something. If project have resources only for density(hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi), I guess "xhdpi is used for mdpi" and "xxhdpi is for xhdpi". But I could not found any document about it.

Comment: From the same article above, the documentation said: `At runtime, the system ensures the best possible display on the current screen with the following procedure for any given resource: 1) The system uses the appropriate alternative resource; 2) If no matching resource is available, the system uses the default resource and scales it up or down as needed to match the current screen size and density.`. So if the OS uses `xhdpi` for your test device, it's because it "thinks" that `xhdpi` is the best match for the screen size/density. If you use a smaller screen device, it might pick `mdpi`.